# The value is not taken from the dictionary in JMH when thread is 2?

Tags: multithreading, dictionary, jmh

For a JMH class, Thread number is limited to 1 via **@Threads(1)**.

However, when I get the number of threads using **Thread.activeCount()**, it shows that there are 2 threads.

The simplified version of the code is below:

```
@Fork(1)
@Warmup(iterations = 10)
@Measurement(iterations = 10)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime) 
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS) 
@Threads(1)

public class MyBenchmark {

    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class BState {

        @Setup(Level.Trial) 
        public void initTrial() {

        }

        @TearDown(Level.Trial)
        public void tearDownTrial(){

        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public List<Integer> get(BState state) {

        System.out.println("Thread number: " + Thread.activeCount());
        ...
        List<byte[]> l = new ArrayList<byte[]>(state.dict.get(k));
        ...
    }
}
```

Actually, the value is tried to get **from the dictionary** using its key. However, when 2 threads exist, the key is not able to get from the dictionary, and here **list l becomes []**.

Why the key is not taken? I limit the thread number because of this to 1.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.activeCount()` answers the number of threads in the system, not necessarily the number of benchmark threads. Using that to divide the work between the benchmark threads is dangerous because of this fundamental disconnect. `ThreadParams` may help to get the benchmark thread indexes, if needed, see the [relevant example](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/3769055ad883/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_31_InfraParams.java).

If you want a more conclusive answer, you need to provide MCVE that clearly highlights your problem.